# GCP IoT connection closed because MQTT keep-alive check failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

GCP IoT Core showing error: mqtt: SERVER: The connection was closed because MQTT keep-alive check failed."
Error Message: [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MsLG.jpg

Under the monitoring tab, I can see data sent/received, however I believe the above error is preventing the data being sent to firebase.

Have tried rebuilding the avr-iot device, which indicate data is being sent with no errors.

Is there a specific reason why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by you connecting without MQTT keep alive enabled. It could potentially also be caused by connecting to the Configuration topic with QoS 0 (do not ack messages) instead of QoS 1 (send acknowledge response on receipt).

How are your ETLing your data to Firebase? Out of the box, IoT Core works with [Google Cloud PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs) so you would need to do something similar to what's discussed in [Firebase PubSub events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) to accomplish what you're trying to do.